# Android idea for generating dynamic survey forms from xml

Tags: android, dynamically-generated, survey

I need to generate a survey form programmatically, in which the questions, input types, their answers will be generated by the xml coming from the server

Please help me out with the following -

1. XML proper structure for inputs / queries of the survey form?

Any sample that can help or any suggested xml-structure for inputs are very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I have done similar thing using `json`, structure could contain the field type, question, possible answer, answer type (radio, checkbox, text field)

Comment: You have triple-s XML : http://www.triple-s.org/ ,  then you can use another tools for your survey. Another possibilities is queXML http://quexml.sourceforge.net/ . This 2 XML offer some standardisation for Survey.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using json, here is what it looks like:

```
{"idcalc":"1","grupo":"Transporte","titulo":"transmision","pregunta":"Transmisión","opcion":"vehiculos","tipo":"drdwn"},{"idcalc":"1","grupo":"Transporte","titulo":"kmtrld","pregunta":"¿Cuantos Km viaja al mes en su vehículo?","opcion":"digite el numero","tipo":"inp"},{"idcalc":"1","grupo":"Hogar","titulo":"consluzmens","pregunta":"¿Sabe el consumo de luz en KWh?","opcion":"sino","tipo":"drdwn"}
```

`tipo` at the end is the type of expected answer (`drdwn` for dropdown spinner, `inp` for something you need to type), `opcion` is the name of the table in the database where to look selectable answers from (e.g. vehicles, cities, etc) or "sino" if it is a yes/no answer. pregunta is the actual question to be asked. It might be better to have the possible answers within the json as well if the survey gets to complicated in structure.